# How to read a text file line by line define a count function using groovy script engine in jmeter

Tags: groovy, jmeter, groovyscriptengine

I have a text file contains 45 lines. I need to read the text file line by line based on the counter increment function.

Example: If we read the first line of a line then it prints count value is 1 and so on...

please provide me some good examples.

Comment: What have you tried ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
new File(filename).eachWithIndex() { line, idx ->
    log.info "${idx} : ${line}"
}
```

Comment: I have an A method calling from the main method.  when the main method calls A method the first time it should print the first line from the text file. when A method calls the second time it should print the second line and so on

Answer (score 0):

- `new File('/path/to/your/file').readLines().get(0)` - returns the first line of the file
- `new File('/path/to/your/file').readLines().get(1)` - returns the second line of the file
- etc.

If you need to access the JMeter variable defined by the [Counter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter) configuration element - use `vars` shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance like:

```
new File('/path/to/your/file').readLines().get(vars.get('your_counter_variable') as int))
```

More information:

- [Groovy File.readLines() function](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#readLines())
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)